# ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk node_modules_next_dist_client_dev_noop_js failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I've been following the basics tutorial on the Next.js website and when I got to the [Global Styles step](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/global-styles), I started getting the following runtime error:

```
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk node_modules_next_dist_client_dev_noop_js failed.
(error: http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/fallback/node_modules_next_dist_client_dev_noop_js.js)
```

Error 1:
[image: Screenshot of error (1)]

Error 2:
[image: Screenshot of error (2)]

I followed all the steps exactly and when I close the error pop-up, the app works fine.

If anyone can provide any guidance on this I'd appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 623, accepted):

**Delete the `.next` folder at the root of your project, relaunch your project, and force-refresh your page (Shift+F5 / Cmd+Shift+R) to remove the cache.**

It apparently is a cache issue. After browsing through GH Issues & various blog posts, my conclusion is that nobody knows what the heck is going on with this webpack-related error, probably caused by Next.js's behavior.

Comment: As a side note: this answer is 1 week old, and it already has 5 upvotes. This is a real problem, and wherever it comes from, it needs to be fixed...

Comment: Allow me to add my upvote, happened after modifying rewrites and changing  the pages folder structure... :)

Comment: For those using Nx, I deleted the `/dist/` folder to get it working. Probably actually only needed to trash one of the next folders inside there but yea, that worked for me.

Comment: Not sure why this is selected as the answer, it doesn't have any info on how to solve the problem. The answer from @amin-amin worked for me.

Comment: @MichaelEdwards hi, thanks for the feedback. I guess it's because I answered earlier. amin-amin wrote the same answer, the fact you have to delete the cache is pretty much implied. I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Actually, for me, part of the problem was that I created `postcss.config.js` as shown in the tutorial at https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/styling-tips. Once I deleted that file and then followed the steps of this answer, my project ran well again.

Comment: Thanks @a2br, this had me reverting git commits and I could not figure it out. This solved the issue (now I wonder what will solve the bug!)

Comment: This happened to me when adding a new npm package to a newer project with <100 commits. (Likely doesn't matter, but it was https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0).

Comment: This is the answer, it  happend because of removing and playing with structure

Comment: Holy shit, someone needs to create an issue on Next.js repo. This has 337 upvotes for a reason. **Edit:** someone already [created an issue 21 days ago](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/29455)

Comment: FWIW; Am using VS Code. I think what did it for me was I undeleted a file in the interface via ctrl-z

Comment: Turns out this is still an issue, but this solution worked for me thank you

Comment: I still have this issue and deleting .next folder and hard refresh browser did not solve it. Issue comes randomly

Comment: This happens to me like once a month. Mindblowing that it isn't fixed yet.

Comment: This still appears to be an issue in 2023, NextJS 13, with the app router. However, if I delete the .next folder, the dark mode no longer functions in my app. Very strange.

Comment: This is still an issue as of Dec. 20, 2023. Thankfully, your issue susses it. So if I do a build and deployment, I make sure the .next is purged and then it's fine.

Answer (score 34):

I had this error after removing files from the /public folder.

How I fixed it:

1. Remove your /.next folder.
2. Launch your project again.
3. Force refresh in you browser to delete the cache.

Comment: Last step wasn't necessary in my case. Though it can't hurt to delete cache.

Answer (score 7):

In my case i had my next.js build directory with a different name as hosted with firebase cloud functions.
Follow these similar steps

1. Delete your build (distDir) directory  (mine was called nextjs)
2. Restart the server
3. Force Refresh the browser

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem appeared when I added a plugin to tailwind.config.js (using tailwind)

maybe this will help someone locate strange nextjs behavior

Answer (score 2):

1- Clear cache of your browser

2- Refresh the page

3- Launch your project again

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I couldn't find the .next folder to be deleted.

Delete all the contents of the build / folder. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the .next folder in VSC. The console log generated more errors, so I then restored the folder back to the project. The errors disappeared.

Comment: This error has returned. I have to do more troubleshooting. I'll comment back once this is fully resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case next-sentry 7.51.2 caused this when running locally. Removed it and all is working fine again. It had been running locally just fine for a long time before that, I would guess it's related to errors from 3rd party scripts loaded in Next's Scripts when running locally, in my case one of them threw a CORS-error on localhost.

Using Next 13.0.7.

If you run into this, try and step back one commit at a time and see if you can find any point in history where it's working (`git checkout HEAD^`).